# Group by on nvarchar data showing Chinese and Japanese characters as questionmarks

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to retrieve the count of repetitive rows(ntext data type) in a table and the row data. This column contains Chinese and Japanese characters. These characters appear like question marks once cast to nvarchar(max). So if use group by on this column, its getting grouped with respect to the question marks when I need these to be grouped according to the Chinese or Japanese messages. My query is as follows.

```
SELECT Message, COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM ipi_messagecustomization 
GROUP BY CAST([message] AS varchar(max))  WITH ROLLUP 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Kindly help. thanks all !!

Comment: In the query you posted, `message` is being cast as `varchar(max)` in the `GROUP BY` clause - is this a typo made when posting or might this be the cause of your error? What's the original datatype of `Message`?

Comment: I know that the cause of the error is due to the cast, I just need an alternative solution to solve the problem, the original datatype of Message is ntext. Since I could not use group by I used a cast.

Comment: Have you tried `CAST([message] AS nvarchar(max))`? (note the additional "n")

Comment: Thanks Ed but I already found a solution..